# Projection matrix product under operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, projection-matrices, unitary-matrices

I've come across a question that is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2674994), but somewhat "reversed" in the role of the unitary matrix.

Suppose I have matrix product $A\, P\, B$ where $A$, $B$ are generic real matrices and $P$ is an $ n \times n $ *projection matrix*.
In this case, does a relationship of the kind
$$ \lVert A\, P\, B \rVert \leq \lVert A\, B\rVert $$
hold?

Of course, if $A^\top \equiv B \equiv x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then this becomes a quadratic form, so the inequality is valid. I am quite unsure whether this makes sense in the general case of $A \not= B$ and both $A$ and $B$ being (compatible) matrices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which norm do you have in mind with $\| \cdot\|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. As a simple counterexample, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&-1\\0&0}, \quad P = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},  \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0}.
$$
We find that $APB = P$ and $AB = 0$. Clearly, $\|APB\| > \|AB\|$.

---

On the other hand, for the particular case of $B = A^T$, the answer is yes. To see that this is the case, it suffices to note that the difference $AA^T - APA^T$ is positive semidefinite. Indeed, we find that
$$
AA^T - APA^T = A(I - P)A^T,
$$
and the fact that $I - P$ is positive semidefinite implies that $A(I - P)A^T$ is positive semidefinite. Thus, $AA^T$ and $APA^T$ are positive semidefinite with $AA^T \succeq APA^T$ relative to the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order), which implies that $\|AA^T\| \geq \|APA^T\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ could be the spectral norm, the Frobenius norm, or any other orthogonally invariant norm $\|\cdot\|$.